# Can't find spring-boot-starter-parent/1.5.1.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, m2e

I created a new and empty Spring Boot 1.5.1 project in STS 3.8.3 using a spring starter. But I can't compile it because I am unable to pull spring-boot-starter-parent. All I receive is:

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   foobar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.1.RELEASE
>   from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not   transfer artifact
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.1.RELEASE
>   from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/  maven2): Connect
>   timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

My PC is behind a company proxy which I configured in user specific settings.xml, it only contains the proxy settings and the path to my repo and nothing more. Usually this proxy works without any problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<settings>
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
  <localRepository>C:\Data\Maven\Repo</localRepository>
  <!-- Proxy settings for access to the central repository -->
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>wonttell</host>
      <port>8118</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.company|localhost</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

From the Maven console I can see that the file was transferred:

> 2/15/17, 8:03:23 PM GMT+1: [INFO] Downloaded
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.1.RELEASE.pom
>   2/15/17, 8:03:23 PM GMT+1: [INFO] Update completed: 10 sec

When I curl the pom using the same proxy this works:
[image]
Running a `Project / Clean ...` and `Maven / Update project` doesn't help. I also installed a standalone maven 3.3.9 alongside the version packaged with STS and configured STS to use this.
I am at wits end ...